# MongoDB Atlas: client.db is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to connect to `MongoDB atlas` in node using the client "mongodb": "^3.5.5" by following [this guide](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-nodejs-mongodb--how-to-get-connected-to-your-database) I do get the log `console.log('connected to db')` but when I try to call `find()` I get the error `client.db is not a function`

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config();

// Connect to MongoDB
 const connectClient = async() => {
  const client = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGODB_CONNECTION_URI);
  try {
      await client.connect();
      console.log('connected to db')
      return client;
  } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
  } finally {
      await client.close();
  }
}
const client = connectClient();

const find = async() => {
  try {
    const cursor = client.db('meetings').collection('inperson').find();
    const results = await cursor.toArray();
    return results
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

app.use(cors());

app.get("/get-meetings", (req, res) => {
  const results = find();
  res.status(200).send({ results });
});

app.listen(8081, () => console.log("Server running on 8081"));
```

The connection URI looks like

```
mongodb+srv://meetingsAPI:ad69xOfovSxAQaD5@meetings-gntor.gcp.mongodb.net/meetings?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Answer (score 0):

Your connectClient function returns a promise, because it's an async function. When you do this:

```
const client = connectClient();
```

"client" variable is pointing to the promise itself, not to the resolved value. This is why it doesn't have the .db property. In order to make the await work, you need to wrap the entire code in an "immediately invoked function expression", like this:

```
//Make sure any code before this ends with seimicolon
(async()=>{
    //code...
    const client = await connectClient();
    //code...
    app.listen(8081, () => console.log("Server running on 8081"));

})()
```

There are of course alternatives to this, but i think it's the best approach. You can take a look here:https://dev.to/codeprototype/async-without-await-await-without-async--oom